# Partial Template Specialization SFINAE

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae

I have the following class templates:

```
template<bool head, bool... tail> 
struct var_and {
    static constexpr bool value = head && var_and<tail...>::value;
};

template<bool b> struct var_and<b> {
    static constexpr bool value = b;
};

template<typename... Ts>
struct type_list {};

template <typename T, typename Enable = void>
class foo;

template <typename... T>
class foo<type_list<T...>, std::enable_if_t<var_and<std::is_integral_v<T>...>::value>> {};
```

When I try to match the specialization:

```
foo<type_list<int, int, int>> test{};
```

I get an error:

```
Error C2079 'test' uses undefined class 'ECS::foo<ECS::type_list<int,int,int>,void>'
```

At the same time I get these errors:

```
more than one partial specialization matches the template argument list of class "ECS::foo<ECS::type_list<int, int, int>, void>" 
"ECS::foo<ECS::type_list<T...>, std::enable_if_t<ECS::var_and<std::is_integral_v<T>...>::value, void>>"          
"ECS::foo<ECS::type_list<T...>, std::enable_if_t<ECS::var_and<std::is_integral_v<T>...>::value, void>>"
... (The exact same error message 6 more times)
```

How can I use SFINAE specifically to enforce type traits of a types in a variadic type pack?

I had no trouble getting it to work for a single type argument:
http://www.cppsamples.com/common-tasks/class-template-sfinae.html

I know I can simply use a static_assert, but I was wondering if it is also possible without.

Comment: From the output of the compiler it seems you are using msvc. This code works perfectly fine with gcc and clang (see http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/36b9eecd91763aaf)... So, msvc bug? Either that or you did not give us all the code being compiled :)

Comment: This exact code compiled with msvc gives the same error: http://rextester.com/NIU85113. So I'm assuming it's a bug then?

Comment: Actually I notice now that that link shows a slightly different error. The same code ran on http://webcompiler.cloudapp.net/ gives the same error though, and it makes use of a more recent compiler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Workaround could look as follows:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <bool...>
struct bool_pack { };

template <bool... Bs>
using var_and = std::is_same<bool_pack<true, Bs...>, bool_pack<Bs..., true>>;

template<typename... Ts>
struct type_list {};

template <typename T, typename Enable = void>
class foo;

template <typename... T>
class foo<type_list<T...>, std::enable_if_t<var_and<std::is_integral<T>::value...>::value>> {};

int main()
{
    foo<type_list<int, int, int>> {};
}
```

[[live demo]](http://rextester.com/RNRKJ94534)

Comment: Replacing my var_and with yours does indeed compile. Interesting.. Is this a known issue with MSVC?

Comment: not sure... there also seemed to be a problem with `std::is_integral_v<T>` usage I replace it with `std::is_integral<T>::value`